# How to put < or > in an android button

Tags: android, layout, button

Eclipse doesn't accept the less than symbol for the button text, is there a way to escape it so it shows on the button?

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_prev_line"
        android:text="<line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Have you tried `&lt;` or `&gt;` ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

escape it `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`

in general you should escape the following characters:

```
< &lt;
> &gt;
" &quot;
& &amp;
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `&lt;` or `&#60;`

Answer (score 1):

Yes yoh need to try the

```
< &lt;
> &gt;
```